# detalle al eliminar contacto c++

Tags: c++

Tengo la siguiente agenda, a la hora de eliminar elimina el primer registro y no el que se esta buscando. No logro entender el porque hace eso.

La agenda esta realizada con funciones.

Este es una parte del código:

```
 class agenda
 {
public:
    char nombre[35], dom[50], tel[20], cor[30];
    void Capturar();
    void Mostrar();
    void Buscar();
    void Modificar();
    void Eliminar();
  }trabajadores[10];

 int bandera,i,contador;
 char buscado[35];


void agenda::Eliminar()
{
    int i,j;
    bandera = 1;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(buscado,nombre)==0)
        {
            trabajadores[i] = trabajadores[i+1];
            for(j=0; j < contador; j++)
            {

                trabajadores[j] = trabajadores[j+1];
            }//fin de for
            trabajadores[i].Mostrar();
            i--;
            contador--;
        }//fin de if    
    }//fin del for
```

Asi lo mando a llamar:

```
        case 5:
            bandera=0;
            system("cls");
            cout<<"\n Nombre de persona a buscar para eliminar:";
            cin.ignore();
            cin.getline(buscado,35);
            for(i=0;i<contador;i++)
            {
                trabajadores[i].Eliminar();
            }
            if(bandera==0)
            {
                cout<<"\n NO EXISTE PERSONA BUSCADA.";
            }
            cout<<endl;
            system("pause");
            break;
```

como les menciono. solo elimina el primer registro.

Envio un ejemplo:

[image: Menu]

[image: captura]

[image: todos]

[image: eliminado]

[image: todos1]

[image: buscado]

[image: buscado1]

Espero y me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Verifica que el valor que quieres eliminar llegue a la función Eliminar(), puedes imprimir en pantalla dentro de esa función.

Comment: @Eric como hago eso. Imprimo el contacto buscado y si lo encuentra los  muestro asi: `trabajadores[i].Mostrar();` pero aun asi borra el primero.

Comment: En dónde asignas el valor a contador?

Comment: cuando se ingresa un contacto, se incrementa en uno `contador++`

Comment: Hay un for en la función Eliminar que dice i<10. Por qué el 10?

Comment: @Eric es el maximo de contactos permitidos, pero ya lo cambia a `for(i=0;i<contador;i++)` para que solo recorra los campos ingresados.